# Encrypt URL parameters in PHP and decrypt in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, encryption

I have the following situation - online coloring pages that work in JavaScript. I'll be passing the coloring image URI to the script. I'd like to encrypt that URI somehow so that it's not that easy for bots to download my coloring images:

http://01smile.com/products/games/html5games/coloringbook_3%28mass%20parameter%20beta%29/index.html?i=http://01smile.com/products/games/girl.gif&p=http://01smile.com/products/games/paper.png

So the above link will be pasted on a page generated with PHP.

What encryption procedure could I use in PHP to encrypt the image URI that would I then be able to decrypt in JavaScript? I'm not looking for some high level of security - just to deter scraper bots.

Comment: don't pass the actual information then. have a database of urls and pass around the url's IDs. `p=42` wouldn't reveal what the image is or where it's coming from.

Comment: give the urls to the client in json or a script block; bots hate JS.

Comment: Making something "not easy for bots" and then providing JavaScript source on how to decode it is self-defeating. Why not just wall off bots with a rate limiter?

Comment: The JS script isn't my own creation - I bought it as is and I'm pretty much clueless to JS, but as far as I understand JS can't access a DB on a server and besides that would be a lot of trouble.